# does every context correspond to only one activity instance

Tags: android, android-activity

there are getApplicatinoContext() method in acitvity class.so i wonder if every context correspond to only one acitivity instance.if not,context correspond to what?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities, Services, and Application classes are the most major Context inherited objects. The Application's context persists through the life of the application. The Context provides services for getting system resources and their management. This includes things like layouts, assets, etc.

Each Activity itself inherits context, note that if a configuration changes (usually screen rotation) while the activity is running. It will kill the activity and recreate it since the old Context is now invalid. Android has to load a different set of resources to accommodate the change.

You can even create your own contexts. Context.createPackageContext.

You always want to use the Context that has a lifecycle that's closest to what you want to work against.

1. Activity - Operations invoked
   against the activity itself will
   want to just use the activity
   context.
2. Service - Defer to services
   for long running operations and use
   that as the handle.
3. Application -
   Try not to use this but in rare
   cases it does make sense.